# Use StoreKit in tvOS to show movie and tvShow detail view

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes, storekit, tvos

I want to bring my iPhone app to tvOS and in my app you can open movies and tvShows in the SkStoreProductViewController of StoreKit (to buy them or get infos). Now this class is PROHIBITED in tvOS and I need an other way that people can buy movies in tvOS coming from my App. So when someone click on a move in my app, I want that the user can buy this movie in "iTunes" (or movie app in tvOS). The best would be similar like SKProductViewController but this seems to be prohibited.

Somebody know how this can work?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ApplicationDelegate's `application:openURL:options:` call with the iTunes URL (the "old school" way before SkStoreProductViewController was introduced).

Make sure your affiliate code is encoded in the URL (I assume this is a part of your business model).
This can help you with the links :
https://autolinkmaker.itunes.apple.com
https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/en-us/